# 'screen' app & video output

Tags: monitor, gnu-screen

I am using 'screen' app so that I can view a running process via SSH remotely, the PC with the process has lightdm disabled. If I switch on the monitor (from Dsub output) I see a command line like readout, but how can I get the output of 'screen' to the video output / monitor, and see the same process as I can see remotely on SSH..?

(PC has no keyboard/mouse attached - looking for a solution / command I can send via SSH remotely...)

Also: if I were to attach a keyboard, the output of the monitor at the PC does not have the usual command prompt, i.e: user@desktop:~$, it has a readout of /dev/sda/ clean, etc, etc. and occasional reports of processes starting, i.e firewall started [OK] - but no command prompt, without which I'm lost as to how to start monitoring a screen process...?

Thanks

Comment: @Videonauth the question isn't about how to use screen itself entirely. The screen-relevant part would be how to have screen attached to two terminals simultaneously. The main part of the question is how to change a different terminal to be logged in and attached to this screen session, for which there is no keyboard to log in on said terminal (tty).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend byobu. http://byobu.co/

It's a terminal multiplexer. Or you can google that term to find other solutions

To use it to get multiplexing you can just open two terminal sessions on the same machine and byobu on both of them.

Comment: Could you expand on how to use byobu to accomplish JW8888's goal. - [from review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/783956)

Comment: Thanks, had a look at byobu, I'm as lost as to getting that on the main monitor without a command prompt as I am with Screen, but thanks anyway..!